# postgres 12 suddenly stop accepting connection: connection to server on socket "var/run/postgresql/.s.pgsql.5432 failed no such file or directory

Tags: server, 22.04, postgresql, database, plex

I don't know whats going on, my database just stop running. suddenly when I want to run postgres using user postgres (*`$postgres psql`*), it gives me error "**connection to server on socket "var/run/postgresql/.s.pgsql.5432" failed**"

I just had this database for 30 minutes, from a fresh setup.
Prior to the error, I was doing testing on WAL files. I recorded every steps :

1. do query `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM pg_ls_dir('pg_wal') WHERE pg_ls_dir ~ '^[0-9A-F]{24}'`;
2. Create table and Insert some records
3. Change parameters using nano. Some parameters that I change : `max_wal_size, replication_mode, checkpoint_timeout,` ,. Restart postgres service, it is still fine.
4. Doing `CHECKPOINT`.
5. do query `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM pg_ls_dir('pg_wal') WHERE pg_ls_dir ~ '^[0-9A-F]{24}'`;
6. Do change parameter. And restart pg service using `sudo systemctl restart postgresql.service`
7. Change user to postgres and run `psql`. From here, I lost my database, can not connect anymore.

It was working just fine and normal. This is the second time happening within a couple of hours. The last time I didn't know what I did but I reinstalled it again by removing the old installation first.

This is so annoying. I don't know what's going on and how to fix it. I follow some possible suggestions available on the web but none worked.

please help.

This is my testing environment: Postgres 12. Ubuntu Server 64bit v22.04 running on VM.

thanks

Comment: `"var/run/postgresql/.s.pgsql.5432` is a configuration mistake. There HAS to be a `/` in front of `var`.

Comment: what causing it to change ? I didn't even touch anything about unix_socket

Comment: the `unix_server_directories` is stil '/var/run/postgresql'  @Rinzwind

Comment: That is the one I meant ;-)  so that seems to be OK. Puzzled me is :P `5432` is the port you used for connecting?

Comment: yes. its. It was just really fine. I can do a couple service restarts.